# Best way of calculating stripe taxamo price including tax

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments, taxamo

Hi I'm curious of how to best calculate the price including VAT for a product pre checkout. Currently the only way I found is creating a order containing the item and then fetching the tax and price from the order. This however creates a lot of redundant orders and seems sub optimal. Is there a way to do this calculation without creating an order?

```
def get_price 
  location = current_user.location
  location_data = APP_CONFIG['country_list'][location]
  currency = location_data['currency']
  country_code = location_data['code']
  product_id = APP_CONFIG['stripe_reconstruction_ids'][currency]
  product = Stripe::Product.retrieve(product_id)
  product_sku = product['skus']['data'][0]['id']
  ip = request.remote_ip

  order = Stripe::Order.create(
    :currency => currency,
    :customer => current_user.stripe_id,
    :items => [
        {
            :type => 'sku',
            :parent => product_sku,
            :quantity => 1,
            :currency => currency
        }
    ],
    :email => current_user.email,
    :metadata => {
      :buyer_ip => ip,
      :billing_country_code => country_code,
      :product_type => 'e-service'
    }
  )


  render :json => order, :status => 200 and return


rescue => error
    logger.error error.message
    render :json => { message: "Could not fetch the correct price." }, :status => 500 and return
end
```

---

**UPDATE**

After talking to the stripe support my proposal seems to be the best way to  do this at the moment. I suggested to them that it would be nice if developers could set a flag on the order that it was just for pricing information to avoid creating an order that would not later be used for a payment. They said they would deliver this suggestion to their developers. Perhaps we will have a better way to do this in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Taxamo's  API [Calculate tax](https://www.taxamo.com/apidocs/api/v1/tax/docs.html#POSTcalculate) endpoint (Ruby client lib is [available](https://www.taxamo.com/doc/api/ruby/)).

Note that if setting `buyer_ip` private token must be used, otherwise field is ignored.

Example curl call:

```
curl -X 'POST' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \
 '{
      "transaction": {
          "currency_code": "EUR",
          "transaction_lines": [
              {
                  "custom_id": "line1",
                  "product_type": "e-service",
                  "amount": 100
              }
          ],
          "billing_country_code": "SOME_COUNTRY_CODE",
          "buyer_ip": "SOME_IP"
      },
      "private_token": "YOUR_PRIVATE_TOKEN"
  }' \
 https://api.taxamo.com/api/v1/tax/calculate | python -m json.tool
```